# How can I add time frame in x axis?

Tags: r

I'm new to using R and ggplot2, and I cannot figure out how to fix the issue with the graph I am trying to create.

Here is what the graph looks like at the moment. I have dates on the x-axis, but for some reason, they don't give an axis with proper leveling. I got a black line inside my x-axis. But I need to show dates on this axis and the date will look like 2020-01 and so on.

[image]

Also, when I change time formate as.POSIXct(ds$Time) then they give me the right formatting in the x-axis. But I got another error related to the time gap because my dataset has several missing hours which I excluded from my dataframe.

[image]

This is my working code

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the data I am working with:

[image]

I will be grateful to you if you could kindly help me to resolve my error. Also, I am really sorry if my codes are messy ;).

Comment: if you would like to receive help, you should facilitate the code. Try to write a reproducible example.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Someone might want to copy-paste it for the answer etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is not a black line in your axis text. It's just a lot of labels overlapping.
Try something like this to rotate the axis text

```r
your_plot + theme(
  axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1),
)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually, I do not have continuous data (per hour). There are several missing hours, which I haven't included in the .csv file.

Comment: Also, when I change time formate as.POSIXct(ds$Time) then they give me the right formatting in the x-axis. But I got another error related to the time gap because my dataset has several missing hours which I excluded from my data frame.